# How do I fix Unity textmeshpro error after updating 2018.1 to 2018.3?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

After updating from unity 2018.1 to Unity 2018.3, there is a bunch of error messages about text mesh pro. Here are the error messages
/Users/administrator/Dropbox/Sebastian/home/coding/Unity/Experimental Project/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.3.0/Scripts/Runtime/TMP_Text.cs(4929,40): error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: `TMPro.TMPro_ExtensionMethods.Multiply(this UnityEngine.Color32, UnityEngine.Color32)' and`TMPro.TMPro_ExtensionMethods.Multiply(this UnityEngine.Color32, UnityEngine.Color32)'

/Users/administrator/Dropbox/Sebastian/home/coding/Unity/Experimental Project/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.3.0/Scripts/Runtime/TMPro_Private.cs(3552,92): error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: `TMPro.TMPro_ExtensionMethods.Compare(this UnityEngine.Color32, UnityEngine.Color32)' and`TMPro.TMPro_ExtensionMethods.Compare(this UnityEngine.Color32, UnityEngine.Color32)'

Multiple plugins with the same name 'tmpro_plugin' (found at 'Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro/Plugins/64 Bit Plugins/TMPro_Plugin.bundle' and 'Assets/Downloaded Assets/TextMesh Pro/Plugins/64 Bit Plugins/TMPro_Plugin.bundle'). That means one or more plugins are set to be compatible with Editor. Only one plugin at the time can be used by Editor.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 folders of TMP in your project, one was probably added from the packages after the upgrade.
find them and remove the new one **for a quick fix**...
or do this: http://blog.collectivemass.com/2018/09/upgrading-textmesh-pro/